# how to access the Chatter page of salesforce1

Tags: chatter

I was trying to access the chatter page of salesforce1 using another app from an iOS device but it gives me the message that "the object home page you are trying to access isn't available in Salesforce1". I used to be able to access it.

Is this still how you access the chatter of salesforce1?

salesforce1://Chatter/home

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most recent documentation for Salesforce1 URL Schemes
[enter link description here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce1_url_schemes.pdf)